# events recognizing special characters in IE10 vs IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, dom-events, internet-explorer-10

The answer already available on Stack Overflow is not a solution to my question..

I can check special characters by keycode but **both dot and delete are giving same key code** 46...

What to do in such situations to identify a special character  ?

```
function keypress(ev) 
    {
        if(ev.which == 0)
        {
            alert('pressed character is special handling character like del,Home,Navigation buttons, etc');
        } else {
            alert('pressed character is normal character');
        }
        if(ev.keycode){
            var k = ev.keycode;
            alert('ascii value of pressed character is ....' + k);
        }
    }
```

If I am using IE8... ev.which is becoming zero and entering 'if' block and printing alert if the pressed character is special character... otherwise it goes to 'else' block...

But in IE10 , It is going to 'else' block always for both special and normal characters...

Surprisingly, dot and delete are having same ascii value 46 in IE10..  printing the same in alert of the keycode 'if' block....

How can I distinguish normal and special characters pressed in IE10.....

Comment: How you are calling function `keypress`??? `window.onkeyup = keypress;`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `onkeydown` event. The `event.which` is recognized as expected if we use that.

[Working Demo of distinction of `.` and `Delete` buttons](http://jsbin.com/dasataxe/1/edit?html,js,output).

HTML:

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="keypress(event)" />
```

JS:

```
function keypress(event) 
{
    alert("something pressed..");

    alert("event.which = " + event.which);

    if(event.which === 46)
    {
        alert('Delete button pressed');
    } else  if(event.which === 190) {
        alert('. button pressed');
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** It seems `.` and `>` have same key code `190` in keydown event.
To identify these two elements which are on the same key, we need to track if the `Shift` key is pressed.

Here is one way to do it:

```
var prevKey = "";

function keypress(event) 
{  
    if(event.which === 16)    // only Shift key
        prevKey = "Shift";

    if(prevKey === "Shift" && event.which === 190){    // Shift + . key
        alert("> key pressed");
        prevKey = "Something else";
    }       

}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/dasataxe/2/edit)

Comment: Dot and '>' have same key code 190 in keydown event.. Please help me to handle that event aswell.....

Comment: @ANILBABU Please refer to the EDIT in the answer above. I hope it helps! :)

Comment: One more issue Rahul.. Right arrow and single quote are having same key code.. Please help me out to distinguish these two events............

Comment: @ANILBABU You can write a same mechanism as I did above. Stakoverflow is not a solutions provider for each and every problem. **Learn** from my answer above.

Comment: hmm @Rahul Desai ... There is no shift event in those 2 to distinguish............ Any have thanks for your help

Comment: @ANILBABU I just checked, the `'` has key code = `222` and right arrow key code = `39`. Tested in Chrome v36.